# Playing YouTube video in jQuery mobile site. Custom thumb

Tags: jquery-mobile, youtube

I have a mobile site built in jQuery mobile. On it, there is a custom graphic linking to a youtube video.

Currently, on the iPhone and Android, when you click (touch) the graphic it opens the youtube app and plays the video from there. Ideally, I would like this to open and play in an overlay within the browser. Is this achievable at all with youtube without using the iframe embed?

Using the iFrame embed is not really an option as the graphic linking to the video is an integral part of the design.